# SAS proc format dynamic values

Tags: sas

```
PROC FORMAT;   
  VALUE $Gender 'M'='Male'                    
                'F'='Female';
```

In the above I am passing the value for processing format as 'm'= 'male'
And 'f'='female' ... The same way I need that values to be passed from a file and the values of process format comes dynamically. How do I do that. 
Like I need to pass the above mapping m=male, f=female from a file and read the file and pass that mapping to proceed format dynamically.

Comment: Are you just asking how to use the `CNTLIN=` option of `PROC FORMAT`?

Comment: Let me be more clear. As mentioned above I need to pass the values of a variable gender dynamically. I don't know how to do it. Not sure what is cntlin option.

Comment: Pass the values from where to where?  I thought you were talking about how to define a format. The CNTLIN= option lets you use a dataset to define a format.

Comment: I need to put the values in a text file with comma delimited like below ex: in text file values should be like in line 1:  M,male line2: f,female now when I read this file then I should be able to pass the above values to proceed format. Suppose I read and store the above values to a variable like column 1 will have m and f and coumn2 will have male and female... My proc stmt should be like                       PROC FORMAT;   
  VALUE $Gender coumn1=column2 ;        
                Where coulmn1 and coulmn2 should be a variable dynamically assigned values from text file is this possible?

Comment: Can you edit the question to clarify what is your starting point and what do you want to achieve?  Are you starting with the code you posted? Are you starting with a text file?  What do you want out? A defined format? A dataset? A text file?

Answer (score 1):

To do what you are asking, is done if you can place your data into Data set, two steps process
1- Get your raw data into data set
2- Use above data set to get desired format
so let do this-

*step 1-;

```
DATA fmt;
 Infile "Textfile.txt" DSD ;
 Retain fmtname '$myfmt';  /*myfmt is what your format name*/;
 Length start $2 label $50;
 Input start label ;
RUN;
```

Now since above code will create a dataset with Male female information use same dataset to create your format.

*Step2:

```
PROC FORMAT CNTLIN=fmt;
RUN;
```

The simplest way to create a format from a data set is to use the CNTLIN= option in PROC FORMAT. 
REQUIRED VARIABLES IN THE FORMAT DATASET (FMTNAME, START, AND LABEL) 
Variable Used for

FMTNAME-  The format name
START  -  The left side of the formatting = sign (assumed character) –
must be unique unless defining a Multi-Label format
LABEL-  The right side of the formatting = sign

Comment: Ok I am trying that. I have my format like                                 PROC FORMAT;   
  VALUE $Gender 'M'='Male'                    
                'F'='Female';                                                                                    VALUE $AGE 'M'=20.           'F'=30                                                            SO NOW I CAN DO LIKE BELOW.                                                            PROC FORMAT CNTLIN=FMT;.    PROC FORMAT CNTLIN=FMTAGE.   IS THIS CORRECT?

Comment: This worked but I have a small problem in the process format value....if I don't have an input start I have mentioned it as other=xxxxxx which means if the start value is not present in the input then assign it to xxxxxx. How do I achieve that now using the above way?

Comment: @santhanj That's a great question, one that you should ask as a separate question rather than appending to this one!  (Or, search for answers on the site, as it's been answered several times.)

Comment: Thanks all I was able to achieve what meant. Now the question I have is I have a bigger problem as I am getting "this range is repeated or overlapped"... To be specific my values of label are repeating I mean my format has repeated values like a=aa b=aa c=as kind of. How do I resolve this error. When I use the hlo=M as muntilqbel option it gives double the data...